# Java - Getting "serverWebExchange cannot be null" when sending request using Spring Security WebClient

Tags: java, webclient, spring-security-oauth2

I am getting "serverWebExchange cannot be null" when sending request using Spring Security WebClient. Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class myonfig {
  @Bean
  ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations() {
    ClientRegistration registration = 
      ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("authProvider")
                        .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                        .clientId(clientId)
                        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                        .scope(scope)
                        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                        .build();
    
      return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
      }

    @Bean(name = "mybean")
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {

    InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = 
       new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new 
       ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations,
                                                                                                                      new AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(clientService));

    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("authProvider");

    return WebClient.builder()
                    .filter(oauth)                     
                    .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    })
                    .build();
 }
```

And the class making the call:

```
{
   ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;
    try {
        responseEntity = webClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(valueString))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class)
                .block();
  }
```

Tried to do some research on serverWebExchange, but didn't find how to use it.  Can someone please let me know why I am getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: A similar exception has been reported on github - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8230. May be you could take a look at that and figure out an equivalent approach for your case? Not really an answer. Just a pointer to a potentially helpful hint .

Comment: Another similar looking error on gitmemory - https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/spring-projects/spring-security/8444/621567261. Quote `However, switching the ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository to a ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService makes the code run.`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I impletemented for one of my springboot application which is reactive using webflux, springboot version 2.6.5, and operates outside of the context of a ServerWebExchange, e.g. in a scheduled/background thread and/or in the service-tier.

The minimal configurations are:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;


@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MyWebClient {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("someWebClient") // -----> 1
    public WebClient someWebClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) { // -----> 2, 3
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build(); // -----> 4
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                                 authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider); // -----> 5
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          my-token-provider:
            token-uri: https://uri-used-to-generate-token
        registration:
          my-token-clientid:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: post
            client-id: clientIdReplacewithYour
            client-secret: clientSecretReplaceWithYour
            provider: my-token-provider
```

**Using webClient:**

```
return webClient
            .method(method)
            .uri(uri)
            .body(Mono.justOrEmpty(requestBody), Object.class)
            .headers(headers)
            .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId(clientId)) // -----> 6
            .exchangeToMono(responseHandler);
```

some details as pointed as comments in the above code:

1. created the WebClient bean with a qualifier `"someWebClient"` as I want to use that qualifier in another class while injecting
2. `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository` will be auto created and passed by springboot with the default configurations
3. `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService` will be auto created and passed by springboot with the default configurations
4. I used the clientCredentials() as I am using machine-machine, AKS operating outside of the context of a ServerWebExchange, AKS without a controller, etc. This line is optional as this already pre-defined in `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` class like `private static final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_PROVIDER = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();`
5. `authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider` - use this if you built your own `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` and want to use it by default. If you want to use springboot out of the box config, don't add this and point 4 in the code.
6. pass the clientId as a parameter - if you have multiple clientId's in application.yaml, you can send clientId as a parameter.